Access log for encrypted thumb drive
I have a USB thumb drive that’s encrypted using Disk Utility standard encryption, so the drive requires a password to access the data/files.
My question is, is there a log of each time the USB drive is accessed, mounted to a computer, or opened?
If I plug it in, type in the password, and access the files, will I be able to see the last time the drive was accessed? (Logged into).
Is the history log only available if the thumb drive is plugged into the same computer or is the history there for anyone with the password?

Mounting and unmounting is not logged to the drive. Each computer the drive is connected to will log these events in its own log database.
For a Mac this is the Unified Log.  But this is not long term logging, rather it is for diagnostic purposes. It can be viewed by anyone with the appropriate permissions.
On a Mac there is no long term log of disk mounting, and nothing to display the last time a disk was mounted.
You will find old questions and answers that refer to looking in /var/log/system.log, but disk mounts are no longer logged there.

Thank you. When I right click on a non-encrypted thumb drive and select get info I can when the drive was last “opened”.
Is this not the case with an encrypted drive ?

Also if I log into the encrypted drive and download or open files, will there be a “last modified” info on that file the next time the drive is opened / logged into if it’s opened on a different computer ?

@BW801 Get Info tells you the last opened time of the drive (on this Mac only??) - encrypted or not. But not a log. Depending on the format of the drive, then the file last modified should be updated on the drive when the file is modified. If that is sufficient, use that.  But that doesn't help if the file isn't modified. So again does not provide a log of when encrypted drive was used.
